# Removing annotation string from the NSmutableString

Tags: objective-c, ios, data-structures, android-mapview, nsmutablestring

I am working on mapView project. My project will take only 5 annotations on the map. Once new annotation will be added, then first annotation will be drop. I am keeping all annotations latitude and longtitude into NSMutableStringArray. Is there any short way to implement this round robin fashion. First in last out.

for example my nsmutable string:

```
 [12.99, 35.97: 35.85,94.53: 45.44,98.91]
```

How could I delete first object (each string separated by  column operator :) from the string to acquire the following:

```
 [35.85,94.53: 45.44,98.91]
```

Comment: You are using an object oriented language so why not model it in an OO way? There should probably be some kind of Queue object managing the annotations queue. Then there should also be some kind of Coordinate object keeping latitude and longitude together in a neat bundle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it work, my solution is below:

```
NSMutableString *absolute=[NSMutableString stringWithString:pinPoints];
          NSLog(@"before absolute: %@",absolute);

          NSArray *placemarks=[absolute componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
          if([placemarks count]>5)
          {
          //NSLog(@"%@",[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]);
          NSMutableString *string1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString: [placemarks objectAtIndex:0]];
          [absolute replaceOccurrencesOfString:string1 withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,[pinPoints length])];
          pinPoints=absolute;
          }
          NSLog(@"after absolute: %@",absolute);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with using the `NSMutableArray` itself. or maybe I didnt understand your question?

```
NSMutableArray *queue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if([queue count] >= 5)
    [queue addObject: myObject];  // adds at end
else
    object = [queue objectAtIndex:5];  // take out the first added object
    [queue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I am using NSMUTABLESTRIING because it will help me to append string to url to call data from the server.

Comment: i dont understand the format u are following. What is latitude here and what is longitude? Why cant you use lists in a list. i.e. `[[lat1,long1], [lat2,long2]...]` ?